# EOFError when reading pickle object (with Pandas) that's non-empty

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a .pkl file that stores a a large pandas DataFrame on my computer; every morning a script runs that loads the file, appends new data, and re-saves it.

Today, I stopped the script shortly after it started executing to check something. When I tried to re-run it, though, it threw an error upon trying to reload the .pkl object, saying "EOFError: Ran out of input". From some cursory reading, it seems like this happens when you try to open an empty file. However, on my computer, it still shows this .pkl file isn't empty, containing 33.8 MB of data, in fact.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Most importantly, **is there any chance of recovering this DataFrame?**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can't append to a pickle file. You need to load it, append to the data, then save that.

Comment: fwiw, pickles are not a good serialization format for long-term storage because they depend on the internal data structures of libraries backing objects in them, which can change when updated https://cube-drone.com/196.png

Comment: or more clearly, the DataFrame can probably be recovered, but you may need the exact versions of the libraries which wrote it and should make a copy of your data before you do any more work as good practice - once recovered, write it out in another format such as [Feather](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#feather), which is both typed and self-contained (you may want to do more work to select a rows-oriented format if you only need to append or have less types .. Parquet is touted as a great choice)

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's what I meant. I load it as a DataFrame, append data, and re-save it as a .pkl

Comment: How did you stop the script? If you used Control-C, it might have interrupted it while it was writing the file, so it was written incompletely. You need to restore a good version from a backup, but you've lost anything you tried to add.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, this is what happened. Was able to restore a prior version. Lesson learned on using Ctrl-C on the script!